# Write-Progress function to tell user percent completion of deletion script

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to delete various files and want to write a function that will prompt the user the percentage completed for each file deletion so that the user doesn't think that the script has crashed. Instead of a progress bar such as {000000.... I would rather have the screen print out a percent number like 10% complete.

```bsh
#Variables
$Comp_Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "DMM-dd-yyyy_THH-mm-ss"

#Log Errors
Start-Transcript -Path C:\TEMP\error_Log-$Comp_name-$DateTime.log -Append

# Get the date and time and remove the directory specified in the function
Function Remove-Directory
{
    Param([string]$Location)
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Location -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt $Files.count; $i++) { 
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Deleting files...' -Status $Files[$i].FullName -PercentComplete ($i / ($Files.Count*100))
    Try
    {

        Get-ChildItem $Location -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content C:\TEMP\ModifiedData-$Comp_Name-$DateTime.log
        #Write-Output "SUCCESS: $Location has been been Modified Successfully"
    }
    Catch{Write-Output "ERROR: $Location could be Modified. Please Verify This Location Manually."}
    }
}

#Remove the below files from computer
If ($Comp_Name -eq "X")
{
    Remove-Directory "C:\Users\X"
}

Stop-Transcript

Write-Output "Script Process Complete. Please Check logs for additional details"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `-percentcomplete` you can use one of the other status indicators

`-CurrentOperation "($i / ($Files.Count*100))% complete"`

You may wish to round or cast the percentage to an integer, something like:

`-CurrentOperation "$([int]($i / $Files.Count*100))% complete"`

The order the parameters show up is as follows, so use which one depending on how you want the hierarchy of messages to display.

```
-Activity
-Status
-CurrentOperation
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the line you suggested before hand but my problem now is that the percentage stays at 0% the entire time.

Comment: Figured out the problem the variable for CurrentOperation should be "$([int](($i / ($Files.Count))*100)%"